# Avoid recomputing addplot in beamer with animate

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots, animations, animate

Using beamer and `animate`, is it possible to avoid recomputing some static expensive parts at each step?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}

   \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{15} % frame rate
      \multiframe{10}{rt=0+0.04}{%

       \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=5cm]
            
            % some expensive static computation recomputed at each frame!
            \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5000] ({cos(deg(2*pi*x))},{sin(deg(2*pi*x))});

            % the only animated part, unexpensive
            \node at (axis cs:0,0) {\rt};

        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The graph with axes is typeset once into an `xlrbox` (pkg `xsavebox`), while saving the label position and the lower left bounding box corner as named coordinates. Then, within the animation, a plain `tikzpicture` environment is used to place the saved graph and the animated label by means of Ti*k*Z nodes.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{xlrbox}{Graph}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=5cm]
         
         % some expensive static computation
         \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5000] ({cos(deg(2*pi*x))},{sin(deg(2*pi*x))});

         % save label position
         \coordinate (label) at (axis cs:0,0);

      \end{axis}
      \coordinate (ll) at (current bounding box.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{xlrbox}%
%  
  \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{15} % frame rate
    \multiframe{10}{rt=0+0.04}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (ll) {\theGraph};
        \node at (label) {\rt};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`xlrbox` is used instead of the standard LaTeX `lrbox` as it greatly reduces the PDF file size (1/6 for 10 frames, 1/32 for 100 frames).

Extended example with multiple predefined label positions:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
  \begin{xlrbox}{Graph}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[height=5cm,width=5cm]
         
         % define several labels
         \multido{\i=0+1,\rphi=90+-45}{8}{
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\xpos}{0.8*cos(\rphi)}
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\ypos}{0.8*sin(\rphi)}
           \edef\arg{ (label-\i) at (axis cs:\xpos,\ypos)}
           \expandafter\coordinate\arg;
         }

         % some expensive static computation
         \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5000] ({cos(deg(2*pi*x))},{sin(deg(2*pi*x))});

      \end{axis}
      \coordinate (ll) at (current bounding box.south west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{xlrbox}%
%  
  \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{4} % frame rate
    \multiframe{8}{i=0+1,rphi=90+-45}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep=0pt, anchor=south west] at (ll) {\theGraph};
        \node at (label-\i) {$\rphi$};
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Since in my actual case my `(label)` depended on the counter `rt`, I included `axis` (or `groupplots`) environnement in the loop, and that does the job!

Comment: I would rather create as many label positions `(label-\rt)` as needed in the xlrboxed graph already, using a `foreach` loop. So redundant drawing of axes in the `multiframe` loop could be avoided.

Comment: Actually I did not draw them (using e.g. `axis line style={draw=none}`) but that's certainly better in general. In my case I use `\rt` to read points in a table, so I would have to synchronise the `foreach` counter with the `animate` one (so that the label names match), which reduces a little bit the improvement you propose, maybe.

Comment: I tried your suggestion by adding `\foreach \i in {0,1,...,10} { \node (label-\i) at (axis cs:0,0) {}; }` in the `xlrbox`, but just adding the labels does not compile (it returns a strange error `! Missing \endcsname inserted. <to be read again>  \OT1\i`). I can't find the reason

Comment: Proper expansion of macros is a bit tricky inside `tikzpicture`. See extended example.

Answer (score 1):

TikZ allows you to save a path and use it later. This is also valid for paths created with `\addplot`. You can create and save the expensive path only in the first frame, and then use the path in the following frames:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
   \begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{15} % frame rate
      \multiframe{10}{rt=0+0.04}{%

       \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[
             height=5cm,width=5cm, clip=false, 
             xmin=-1.2, xmax=1.2,ymin=-1.2, ymax=1.2
           ]
           \ifdefined\ExpensivePath
             \draw[use path=\ExpensivePath];
           \else
             \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=5000,save path=\ExpensivePath] ({cos(deg(2*pi*x))},{sin(deg(2*pi*x))});
           \fi

            % the only animated part, unexpensive
           \node at (axis cs:0,0) {\rt};

        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No reason in this case. Your code is more clear. I will edit it.